# Probability of bringing a card that is already in the collection

Tags: probability, bayesian

Let's say there is a card collection that is made of 1,000 different cards. I start calling my friends and each of them brings 15 random cards to the collection. The first friend will bring 100% new cards, the second will bring ~99% new cards, etc.

What would be the formula to estimate the number of "new" cards brought by my nth friend? Assuming all the cards are random.

edit: assuming no duplicates in my friend's cards and assuming the 1,000 cards in the collection have the same level of rarity (i.e. uniformly distributed)

Comment: This is related to the [coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem). The question about the number of new cards for the $k-th$ person is a bit new but might already have been asked. It is similar to the question how many of the cards 1-15 are still not sampled after $k-1$ turns (it doesn't matter whether we choose some fixed set 1-15 or some random set the cards from the $k$-th person). Why do you wanna know this? What is your exact problem here? Is this a puzzle or study question? Do you want en estimate or exact computation?

Comment: Uniformly distributed cards or are some "rare"?  Does each friend's set of cards never have duplicates?

Comment: Also related is the occupancy problem.

Comment: Thank you for the replies! I have added a small edit to extend the question. The question is a slightly simplified version of study question, apologies for not mentioning this.

Comment: You should probably add the `[self-study]` tag and read its tag-wiki https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info , modifying your question accordingly.